# Fluffy Cloud Configurations For .NET

Tags: asp.net, windows, hosting, amazon-web-services, cloud

Very simple question, is there any cloud server enviroments avaliable these days for us .NET guys that rivals Amazons ec2?

EDIT:

PDC 2008 looks like there are some very interesting info, and only 4 days 2 hours  to wait :-). Looks like I need to get saving fast for the conference fee though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold your breath for [PDC 2008](http://www.microsoftpdc.com/) and you'll see.  Also Amazon's EC2 service support for Windows images is in Beta.  [AWS Windows Support Blog Post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2008/10/coming-soon-ama.html)

**Oct 23 Update** : AWS Windows Support Released To Production ([details here](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/))

**Oct 27th Update** : So you held your breath and saw the Reddog folk become "Windows Azure" cloud services and Sitka - SQL Server Data Services.  Lots of activity to read and learn at MSDN, MS PDC site, Channel 9 etc.  Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I use Mosso, a subsidiary of Rackspace. I've been pleased with them.

You can run PHP, Perl, .NET, and RoR on their system.  MySQL as well as SQL Server.

http://www.mosso.com

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Sql Server Data Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/dataservices/default.mspx) and make sure to tune in to PDC 2008 next week.

Answer (score 0):

It's not public yet but EasyDb is very .net-focused, it wraps your tables into an ASMX web service. There was a dnrtv episode on it, http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=121

Answer (score 0):

We took Mosso for a trial run earlier this year, and it was disastrous. On a number of criteria - uptime, customer service, flexibility - we would have been better off a $6/month shared hosting account. And they changed their pricing model midstream from a per-request model to a per-"compute cycle" model, the "compute cycle" being a mysterious proprietary metric that's impossible to optimize for because you don't know how it's calculated - the end result being that you could suddenly find yourself on the hook for thousands of dollars in charges for no good reason.